# Singleton object and the copy module in Python

Tags: python, copy, singleton

I defined this singleton metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    """Metaclass which implements the singleton pattern"""

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self not in self._instances:
            self._instances[self] = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._instances[self]
```

Now, I want to test whether everything works OK. Here is what I've tried:

- I created two objects of the same class (class that has `Singleton` as metaclass) - their `id()` matches
- I created one object and assigned it to a second variable - their `id()` matches
- I imported the `copy` module and copied the first object with `copy.copy()` - their `id()` doesn't match now

I want to know why doesn't the copied object's id match with the original object. Since it's a Singleton, shouldn't the two objects have the same id?

Comment: You copied the object. How should `copy.copy` know about your attempts to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: How is the object copied? Shouldn't it get through the Singleton process and figure out to use the same object? If not, how can I prevent this?

Comment: @linkyndy: no, the `copy` module does not use the metatype to create the copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `copy` module does *not* create a new instance; instead it creates an empty class, and reassigns `__class__` on that object to specifically *avoid* the `__new__` or `__init__` methods of the original.

You'll need to provide a custom `__copy__` hook to return the instance unchanged instead:

```
class Singleton(type):
    """Metaclass which implements the singleton pattern"""

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self not in self._instances:
            self._instances[self] = super(Singleton, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return self._instances[self]

    def __copy__(cls, instance):
        return instance
```

`copy` looks up the `__copy__` method directly on the class; it is instead found on the *metaclass*, looking up `__copy__` on the class will return a bound method, and `copy` (expecting an unbound method) passes in the instance explicitly. This means that there will be *two* arguments passed in to `__copy__`; the first is the class (an instance of the metaclass), the second the instance of that class (`self` in traditional methods).

Unfortunately, `__deepcopy__` is looked up on the instance instead, and the metaclass method is not found.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You made it clear for me. But still have two questions: the docs say that for `__copy__`, `no additional arguments are passed`. What's with `instance`? Also, how to proceed for `deepcopy`? The same way?

Comment: @linkyndy: adjusted to explain the need for two arguments. `__deepcopy__` would take three; the class, instance and memo.

Comment: Understood now. But `__deepcopy__` doesn't work if I return `instance` as in `__copy__`, there will be two different objects. Anyway, I think I shouldn't be bothering with `__deepcopy__` as well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @linkyndy: my analysis was not entirely correct; updated, `__deepcopy__` would require altering the class itself. However, I wonder if subverting deepcopying is a good idea at all.